# Add bulk entries to Word 2010 Autocorrect

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

How do you add a hundred or so key/value rich text entries to Word 2010's Autocorrect? Can you import an Excel file containing two columns with the values and have Word add them to its Autocorrect dictionary? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this to solve the problem: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/15/use-powershell-to-add-bulk-autocorrect-entries-to-word.aspx